# Не работает nth-child для последующих элементов

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, nth-of-type

Необходимо задать иконку для каждого блока с классом platform__item-img.
Почему то :nth-child(1) и :nth-child(2) работают корректно, а 3 и 4 нет.
After по такому же принципу работает. Пробывал удалить ::after, не помогло.
так же пробовал удалить :nth-child(1) и :nth-child(2), в таком случае ничего не отображается из иконок.
В инспекторе кода элементы :nth-child(3) и :nth-child(4) не отображаются, браузер их выводит как :nth-child(1) и :nth-child(2).Nth-of-type так же бессилен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML

```
    <div class="platform__wrapper">
        <div class="platform__item">
            <div class="platform__item-img">
                <img class="platform__item-img--img" src="img/platform-1.jpg" alt="platform">
            </div>
            <div class="platform__item-text">
                <h3 class="platform__item-title title-item">
                    Доступ 24/7
                </h3>
                <p class="platform__item-content">
                    Керуйте власним графіком і навчайтесь у будь-який час з будь-якого пристрою. Особистий кабінет доступний з PC, iPad і смартфона.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="platform__item">
            <div class="platform__item-text">
                <h3 class="platform__item-title title-item">
                    Короткі ефективні уроки
                </h3>
                <p class="platform__item-content">
                    Навчання невеликими уроками з навчальними матеріалами і тестами максимально наближеними до тестів ЗНО.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="platform__item-img">
                <img class="platform__item-img--img" src="img/platform-2.jpg" alt="platform">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="platform__item">
            <div class="platform__item-img">
                <img class="platform__item-img--img" src="img/platform-3.jpg" alt="platform">
            </div>
            <div class="platform__item-text">
                <h3 class="platform__item-title title-item">
                    Всі матеріали в особистому кабінеті
                </h3>
                <p class="platform__item-content">
                    Кожен курс послідовно розкладено по поличках. Тренувальні та контрольні тести з відповідями для самоперевірки.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="platform__item">
            <div class="platform__item-text">
                <h3 class="platform__item-title title-item">
                    Вигідніше за заняття з репетитором
                </h3>
                <p class="platform__item-content">
                    70 грн за урок замість 350 грн.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="platform__item-img">
                <img class="platform__item-img--img" src="img/platform-4.jpg" alt="platform">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

&-img {
position: relative;

```
    // === background ===
    &::after {
        content: "";
        background-image: url(../img/background.svg);
        position: absolute;
        width: 444px;
        height: 441px;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 60px;
    }

    &:nth-child(1)::after,
    &:nth-child(3)::after {
        left: 0px;
    }

    &:nth-child(2)::after,
    &:nth-child(4)::after {
        right: 0px;
    }
    // === / background ===

    // === icons ===
    &::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 166px;
        height: 166px;
        bottom: 20px;
    }

    &:nth-child(1)::before {
        background-image: url(../img/keys.svg);
        left: 70px;
    }

    &:nth-child(2)::before {
        background-image: url(../img/table-clock.svg);
        right: 70px;
    }

    &:nth-child(3)::before {
        background-image: url(../img/folders.svg);
        left: 70px;
    }

    &:nth-child(4)::before {
        background-image: url(../img/correction-pen.svg);
        right: 70px;
    }
    // === / icons ===
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете препроцессор SASS с синтаксисом SCSS и используете такой код:

```
&-img { position: relative;
    &:nth-child(3)::before {
        background-image: url(../img/folders.svg);
        left: 70px;
    }
}
```

Если перевести в обычный CSS, то получится:

```
platform__item-img { position: relative; }
platform__item-img:nth-child(3)::before {
    background-image: url(../img/folders.svg);
    left: 70px;
}
```

Это является не верным, так как `platform__item-img` находится внутри `platform__item` и является единственным таким элементом для этого родителя.
Вам нужно считать `platform__item` и внутри его искать `platform__item-img`.